# How to change format of the date in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a given date like this as a list: `["Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018"]`

How can I change this date into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. For example: `"2018-09-05 09:23:03"`

```
date = ["Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018"]
```

Returned should be =

```
"2018-09-05 09:23:03"
```

Comment: are your dates in string format?

Comment: Hey there! Thanks being a new contributor on Stack Overflow. It can be discouraging sometimes when you see your post being downvoted and not getting a response. This is probably because other contributors here want to help, but they want to know what you have tried, what didn't work for you, what research you have done and where you exactly need some help. If it seems like you haven't done any of those things, you are likely to have a negative experience here. Try editing your post with some of those things I mentioned.

Comment: ^ In particular because the official documentation should be the first place to check: there is [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module, with lots of documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `datetime` module in combination with `dateutil.parser`. Assuming that your input list stores date time strings, you can use the following code:

```
import dateutil.parser as dp
import datetime

nd=dp.parse("Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018")
converted=datetime.datetime.strftime(nd, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(converted)
```

This should print:
`'2018-09-05 09:23:03'`

Note: if the format is unknot to you, then using datetil.parser is quite helpful to extract a datetime object from a date string. However if the format is known, then you may use `datetime.datetime.strptime`. here is a useful link:
https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Comment: I can't use dateutil.parser module. Is there a replacement for that?

Comment: @guven I don't think datetime module allows u to create a datetime object from a string unless the format is known. if you are using random date formatted strings, then dateutil is the way to go. If u already know the format, then u can first create a datetime object from string using the `.strptime` function then convert to a new format as string using the above `strftime`  function

Comment: @GuvenDemirel u can install dateutil like so: `pip3 install python-dateutil`

Comment: One last question where do i type pip3 install python-dateutil?

Comment: to install a python package on a Unix system (Linux distro/MacOS) you would need to execute the above command from your terminal. If you are working with a windows machine, then u need to do something like this: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/